# Is there a way to share vision with opponent in Starcraft 2?

Tags: starcraft-2

There are times that I would like to be able to share vision with my opponents when playing Starcraft 2. This was possible in the original Starcraft, but I can't find a way in Starcraft 2.

Situations in which I would want to share vision include:

- Playing melee games vs friends of much lesser ability. Sharing vision with them gives them an advantage that helps to even the playing field. It makes the game more challenging for myself, it negates surprise as a viable strategy and forces me to rely on other factors to win the game.
- FFA vs friends, where those that have lost (but still have at least one remaining building to avoid being booted out of the game and into the score screen). Those players that have lost may want vision so that they can enjoy the remainder of the match.

Is this possible with standard melee maps?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, this is not possible unless you're playing a custom map, unfortunately.

Answer (score -1):

yes you can! but you need learn assembly code

modify SC2.exe, find fog function

jump 2 bytes for skipping fog function

becuase Copyright issue I can not paste code here

I am sure you can!

Comment: How is this supposed to answer the question?